# Black screen after installing Ubuntu Touch. Galaxy Nexus (maguro)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I just flashed the ubuntu touch files on my gsm Galaxy Nexus (maguro), but when booting after the google logo it just shows a black screen. I've waited for 15 minutes for it to boot, but it didn't.

I did a factory reset before installing, and have also tried going back to android and trying again. my recovery is twrp 2.6.0.0